# How to host a subdomain of a domain which is associated with blogger?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, subdomain, blogger

I have a domain `www.example.com` which is hosted on Blogger platform. Is any hosting site like Blogger, WordPress where I can host my sub-domain like `abc.example.com`?  My original website `www.example.com` will be always hosted into the Blogger platform. If I want to host any of my sub-domains on another hosting site which supports HTML, is it possible?

Comment: Did you buy the domain through Google (via Godaddy) or via someone else? Do you have access to the DNS information for the domain?

Comment: Yah...I buyed this domain and have full DNS access of it.. But I dont buy this domain via GoDaddy.. I buyed this domain via www.bigrock.in

Answer (score 1):

You can buy new hosting and then configure your DNS on your domain to point to the hosting company's server for abc.example.com.

Comment: but by this i will loose my blogger hosting..

Comment: Your blogger hosting should be unaffected. Your blog lives at something.blogspot.com and you've pointed the subdomain www.example.com to point to it (www is just a subdomain like abc). abc.example.com can point to some other host, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find your hosting provider. You can find it on google and microsoft site. I find hostforlife.eu on Microsoft site, check their plan and maybe you are interested.
2. Then add your subdomain on the Control Panel.
3. Please point your IP to the IP server.

Good luck